# Sqlite3: finding average score of 10 distinct people

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. One has an id and a score. The other has columns: id, name. The id in the second table matches one in the first table. A name might have several ids.I want to find n (distinct) names who have the n highest average scores.

I can find 10 distinct names, I can find the average score. However, I don't see how to combine the 2.

select id, id2, avg(score) as avg_score from t1, t2 where t1.id=t2.id2 group by name order by movies.score desc limit 10;

But I'm pretty sure this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT foo.name AS name, AVG(bar.score) AS avgscore
FROM foo
  JOIN bar ON foo.id=bar.id
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY avgscore DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The main thing you were missing was the `AVG` aggregate function to actually average anything. Also, you want to group by name (this makes sure you only get one row per name, and makes `AVG` average the scores for each name), and there's no use for a `HAVING` here.

Comment: So i think i got it working. The output of the names is in alphabetical order, as I want it. Is this just luck? Or is there something I can do to guarantee that I get the n highest avg scores and if there are any ties, then it puts them in alphabetical order?

Comment: @lars you can `ORDER BY score DESC, name ASC` to make the tie-break behavior explicit.